# Format html on dropped in jquery UI

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

When I dropped li from `labelUl` to `tagsTable` it it shows text inside it but I want to drop `i` tag with it also so the li will be like when its dropped `<li>1<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></li>`

```
<ul class="labelUl ">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="tagsTable ui-sortable">
<li>One<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></li>
<li>Two<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </li>
<li>Three<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></li>
</ul>

    function init() {
        $('.labelUl li').draggable({
            helper: function(e) {
                 return '<li><label></label><i class="fa fa-times red" title="Delete control"></i></li>';
            },
            connectToSortable: ".tagsTable"
        });

        $('.tagsTable').sortable({
            placeholder: 'block-placeholder',
            update: function(event, ui) {
                if( $(".active").attr('id') == "view_e" ) { $(ui.item).children().eq(1).removeAttr('hidden'); }
            }
        });
    }
```

Basic demo is here [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BDhara/hcxw2de9/2/)

How can I achieve that..please help

Comment: Maybe put the code in fiddle

Comment: can u check again @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy